# Variables in an abstract base model class (Django)?

Tags: django, django-models

I have several model classes with very similar structures, so I'd like to refactor most of their definitions into an abstract base model class. However, many fields in each model class have at least one unique attribute, despite being otherwise analogous. For example, consider:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='modela_id', primary_key=True)
    label = models.TextField()
    ref = models.ForeignKey('ModelAHelper')

class ModelB(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='modelb_id', primary_key=True)
    label = models.TextField()
    ref = models.ForeignKey('ModelBHelper')
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
class MyBaseModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column=self.class_name.lower()+'_id', primary_key=True)
    label = models.TextField()
    ref = models.ForeignKey(self.class_name+'Helper')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ModelA(MyBaseModel):
    class_name = 'ModelA'

class ModelB(MyBaseModel):
    class_name = 'ModelB'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Suspect you're going to have to delve into metaclasses to make this work, and it won't be pretty.

Answer (score 0):

There probably is someway to get all of that to work but why not just specify the ref field on the new classes and move on?  Your approach is still pretty DRY.

```
class MyBaseModel(models.Model):
    label = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True    

class ModelA(MyBaseModel):
    ref = models.ForeignKey('ModelAHelper')

class ModelB(MyBaseModel):
    ref = models.ForeignKey('ModelBHelper')
```

Comment: I'm working with a large database that is being used across many apps (not all Django), so I can't change the names of the fields. Therefore, every field needs its own `db_column` argument, which will be table-specific, as in the `id` field in the above example.